# Sharepoint: web part programmatically changing permissions, cannot get the changes to persist

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, permissions, web-parts

I'm writing a visual web part in visual studio for sharepoint 2010.  The whole point of this web part is to change permissions around at the click of a button.  I am able to access the permissions and output them to the screen.  I'm able to change the permissions in the objects that I have, and then show the changed permissions on the screen.  My problem is, after everything is done, no actual permissions have been changed.

webpart.TargetLibrary is a text field, inputted elsewhere as the name of the library I wish to investigate.

```
SPListCollection docLibs = m_SharePointWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
SPDocumentLibrary targetLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)(docLibs[webPart.TargetLibrary]);
SPListItemCollection libFolders = targetLib.Folders;
  SPListItem folderItem = libFolders[0];
  SPRoleAssignmentCollection folderRoles = folderItem.RoleAssignments;
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssign = folderRoles[0];
    SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection spRDBC = roleAssign.RoleDefinitionBindings;
    SPRoleDefinition Contribute = spRDBC[0].ParentWeb.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
  folderItem.RoleAssignments[0].RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(Contribute);
  folderItem.Update();
```

This is a somewhat simplified version - the original had some for loops and various bits of other code doing other things.  Regardless, by everything I've been able to piece together from looking online, this code *should* add "Contribute" privs to the first role on the list in the first folder.  As I mentioned, it does so to the local objects, but has no permanent effect.  The Update() call appears to do nothing, and I'm not certain it's meant to be there in this case.  I tried UpdateOverwriteVersion() - that doesn't do anything either.  Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.

As a side note, it's not nearly so much of an issue, but I can't help the feeling that there's a more efficient and straightforward way to get a web object so that I can acquire role definitions by name.  Any advice on that matter would also be appreciated.

Edit: solution moved to answer, below.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answers to both the base and the side note.

For the side note, the following looks like it's the intended way to get an appropriate SPWeb object.

```
SPContext.Current.Web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
```

For the base, the problem is that Sharepoint apparently does not save changing roles inside a SPRoleAssignment - only granting or removing permissions to the folder as a whole.  This may or may not have to do with the fact that I was working inside a folder.  In any case, in order to get it to save, you have to remove the person from SPRoleAssignmentCollection, make changes to their  SPRoleAssignment, and then re-add the changed version.  The correct version of the above code (integrating both answers) is as below.

```
SPRoleDefinition Contribute = SPContext.Current.Web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
SPListCollection docLibs = m_SharePointWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
SPDocumentLibrary targetLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)(docLibs[webPart.TargetLibrary]);
SPListItemCollection libFolders = targetLib.Folders;
  SPListItem folderItem = libFolders[0];
  SPRoleAssignmentCollection folderRoles = folderItem.RoleAssignments;
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssign = folderRoles[0];
    folderRoles.Remove(roleAssign.Member);
    roleAssign.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(Contribute);
    folderRoles.Add(roleAssign);
```